# What is the best way to commit every 200 clients with my ORACLE database request

Tags: database, oracle, commit, execution-time

I have a request in my database which is launched everyday. It's for deleting rows about 750 clients maximum. Now we want to keep that request but we need to make a commit every 200 clients.

Here is the original request :

```
delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR);
delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE2 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR);
```

As you can see the list of client id to delete is in another table. We get it with the select request.

```
select ID_CLI from MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR
```

That list can have 750 client ids maximum.
So to commit every 200 clients i've done it that way :

```
declare i number := 0;
begin
  for r in (select ID_CLI from MKTMLF.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR)
  loop
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 where id_cli = r.id_cli;
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE2 where id_cli = r.id_cli;
    i := i+1;
    if mod(i, 200) = 0 THEN   
          COMMIT;
    end if;
   end loop;
 commit;
end;
```

But my coworker tells me it's a bad idea because if we have 750 ids to delete, there will be 750 times these two requests so 750*2 = 1500 requests! He tells me to use to use the ROWNUM to get the first 200 ids, commit then other 200 etc... So i try it and it's look like this :

```
declare listTotal number := 0;
begin
    select count(1) into listTotal from MKTMLF.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR;
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR where ROWNUM < 201);
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE2 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR where ROWNUM < 201);
commit;
if listTotal > 200 THEN
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from (select tmp.*, rownum r from MKTMLF.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR tmp) where r > 200 and r < 401);
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE2 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from (select tmp.*, rownum r from MKTMLF.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR tmp) where r > 200 and r < 401);
end if;
commit;
if listTotal > 400 THEN
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from (select tmp.*, rownum r from MKTMLF.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR tmp) where r > 400 and r < 601);
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE2 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from (select tmp.*, rownum r from MKTMLF.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR tmp) where r > 400 and r < 601);
end if;
commit;
if listTotal > 600 THEN
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from (select tmp.*, rownum r from MKTMLF.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR tmp) where r > 600 and r < 751);
    delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE2 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from (select tmp.*, rownum r from MKTMLF.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR tmp) where r > 600 and r < 751);
end if;
commit;
end;
```

So i ask myself what's the best way to achieve this? I found the second way a bit too complicated but maybe is faster? Maybe you have another way to do it better?

Comment: This table: MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR  holds the IDs to be deleted.  Once they are deleted from the other tables .. does it matter what happens to this table?  That is, can you also "cleanup" this table by deleting the ones that have been deleted ?

Comment: also .. just curious:  WHY is there a requirement to commit every 200 ?? What's the logic/reasoning behind it ?

Comment: Once we have delete data, each day we reload MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR with new ids. Why they want commit every 200? Because sometimes it fails before the end. I have listed just 2 lines of instructions here for my example but we have a lot of more update and delete in that script.

Comment: what version of Oracle are you on ?

Comment: Does this [autocommmit](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0580__SQL-PLUS-Session-Environment/Showandsetautocommit.htm) feature help? With this you can set a number of DML statemtns to be executed before it commits automatically.

Comment: @Chriz I wouldn't recommend autocommit for this: autocommit is a client feature of sqlplus .. and would be more of a "bandaid" fix to the issue, rather than just building the system properly ;)

Comment: @Ditto Learned something today! I didn't know it's only a client feature. I wouldnt recommend it either, but that'd be part of an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you want to commit every 200 ... "Because sometimes it fails before the end"

Based on that information, I'd recommend using the ERROR_LOGGING clause and keep it in a single statement.
I don't believe breaking it up to commit every 200 is the best way of handling this situation.

Here's what I would recommend:

1) Create an error table for your two tables:

```
  EXECUTE DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('TABLE1', 'TABLE1_ERRLOG');
  EXECUTE DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('TABLE2', 'TABLE2_ERRLOG');
```

(or 1 for each table you are dealing with)

this is a one time setup .. and doesn't have to be redone each day.

2) have your "daily job" run the following delete statements .. including the LOG ERRORS clause:

```
  delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR) 
     LOG ERRORS INTO TABLE1_ERRLOG ('Daily Delete1') REJECT LIMIT 750 ;
```

You can put any number you want for REJECT LIMIT .. I put 750 for now .. since you mentioned you handle up to 750 per day ?  This would allow the script to ATTEMPT to delete everything .. and report all that failed.  If you pick a lower number, it will stop after hitting that many failed deletes.  Adjust to suit your requirements. ;)

```
  delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE2 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR)
     LOG ERRORS INTO TABLE2_ERRLOG ('Daily Delete2') REJECT LIMIT 750 ;
```

3) Have the job look at those 2 error log tables after running and respond accordingly if records exist ...

you can look into them and handle them as you will ... then re-run the DELETE  whenever you wanted to re-try.

(note: deleting a non-existent record is just fine, it wouldn't log any error for that case ... )

Note that this ERROR_LOGGING clause exists for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements. And you only need the 1 ERROR table per base table ... regardless of the INS/UPD/DEL you run ..

in other words ... after creating TABLE1_ERRLOG ... you can then run:

```
     delete from MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 where id_cli in (select ID_CLI from MYSCHEMA.TMP_ID_CLI_SUPPR) 
     LOG ERRORS INTO TABLE1_ERRLOG ('Daily Delete1') REJECT LIMIT 750 ;
```

and

```
     INSERT into MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 ( select * from ... whatever ..)
        LOG ERRORS INTO TABLE1_ERRLOG ('Daily Insert1') REJECT LIMIT 750 ;
```

and also:

```
     UPDATE MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 set some_col = some_value
        where <some condition>
        LOG ERRORS INTO TABLE1_ERRLOG ('Daily Update1') REJECT LIMIT 750 ;
```

And they would all dump the errors into the same Error log table:  TABLE1_ERRLOG
and you can look at column: ORA_ERR_TAG$  to see if it was Del, Ins or Upd .. 
(ie the "comment" you send it .. I used "Daily Delete1", "Daily Insert1" and "Daily Update1" in my example above)

Oracle 10:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8005.htm

example of LOG ERRORs clause:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#BCEGDJDJ

Oracle 11:
https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_8005.htm#SQLRF01505

example of LOG ERRORs clause:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2121671

Comment: Your solution seems perfect, i will try to implement it later because it will take a bit time to prepare this. You said "1 for each table you are dealing with", we are dealing with a lot of tables so i have to take time to do this and i have to convince my coworkers to do that way.

Comment: @Siick:  It may be more overhead initially .. however, the gains over time should be obvious: this solution is scalable if the data grows .. easier to troubleshoot and maintain (locating the offending record(s) is trivial - just look into the ERRLOG table) and it doesn't suffer from "too-many-commits-syndrome" ;)   https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022   Hopefully it works out for you. Good luck!